# How to declare, initializing and instantiate a Struct data-memeber implementing a trait?

Tags: rust

I have been spending some time without any luck in making this program work.

```
trait Factory {
    fn new(text: String) -> Self;
    fn perform_action(&self);
    fn calling_fn(&self);
}

struct ConcreteA {
    text_ : String,
}

impl Factory for ConcreteA {
    fn new(text: String) -> Self {
        ConcreteA {
            text_: text,
        }
    }
    
    fn perform_action(&self) {
        println!("printing from concrete A obj: ");
        
        self.calling_fn()
    }
    
    fn calling_fn(&self) {
        println!("printing from the calling function A obj");
    }
}

struct ConcreteB {
    text_ : String,
}

impl Factory for ConcreteB {
    fn new(text: String) -> Self {
        ConcreteA {
            text_: text,
        }
    }
    
    fn perform_action(&self) {
        println!("printing from concrete B obj: ");
        
        self.calling_fn()
    }
    
    fn calling_fn(&self) {
        println!("printing from the calling function B obj");
    }
}

fn initializer(flag : u32, text: String) -> &'static dyn Factory {
    if flag == 1
        {&ConcreteA::new(text)}
    else // if flag == 2
        {&ConcreteB::new(text)}
}

fn main() {
    {
        let obj = initializer(1, "hello world!");
        obj.perform_action();
    }
    
    {
        let obj = initializer(0, "hello universe!");
        obj.perform_action();
    }
}
```

Also find a link to [the Rust Playground here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7ab22b4b7c032fe6c6cd22d1649300be).

This is an implementation of a Factory pattern on Rust, [everything works just fine](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=14e13cef3ee5afca218220b35ccb51f8) until I start adding some data-members to the struct implementation.

I tried to mitigate this problem using:

- `Box` but that didn't work (maybe I was doing it wrong)
- `fn new(text: String) -> Self where Self: Sized;` (as highlighted by compiler suggestion)
- Tried different combination of the `fn new(&self, text: String) -> Self;`

The slight deviation that I am trying to incorporate in this Factory pattern is with a constraint that I initialize an data-field when I am creating the objects via a factory-method (no matter what type of object gets initialized). I am still learning Rust, and this will be helpful if someone can help me show how to accomplish this in a cleaner way.

Comment: [`where Self: Sized` works for me](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6525f1cf994c53c7f64083967928c262) (after some fixes).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman thank you for your comment. I am think I was not thinking in that way.